# Am I allowed to use other's website in a web view in my app?

Tags: android

I'm making an app for publishing in play stores. One of my app function is using translator, but for now i don't have time to use google translate API. Instead, I made a web view and showing google translate website in it till i update my app in future and use google translate API.
So, Am i allowed to use Other's website in a web View in my app?
Or play store will remove it?
What about using google translate website.
Note that this web view is one of my important part of my app but it's not the main function of what my app do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app won't get declined or removed because of using web view, and you can set a direct link to google translate page as long as your app main primary functionality is not webview.

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:
>
> Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you
> (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do
> so)

According to [Apple's App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality), apps which are just web views are not allowed:

> 4.2 Minimum Functionality
>
> Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it
> beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful,
> unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store.